# Pivoting a series of rating columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In Pandas, I have a data frame, where each row corresponds to a user, and each column to a variable related to that user, including how they rated a certain thing:

```
+----------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+
|      name      |          email           | rating_a | rating_b |
+----------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+
| Someone        | someone@mail.com         |      7.8 |      9.9 |
| Someone Else   | someone.else@mail.com    |      2.4 |      9.2 |
| Another Person | another.person@mail.com  |      3.5 |      7.5 |
+----------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+
```

I want to pivot the table such that one column is the type of rating (`a`, or `b`), another is the rating value (`7.8`, `3.5` etc), and the other columns are the same as above, like this:

```
+----------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
|      name      |          email          | rating_type | rating_value |
+----------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| Someone        | someone@mail.com        | a           |          7.8 |
| Someone        | someone@mail.com        | b           |          9.9 |
| Someone Else   | someone.else@mail.com   | a           |          2.4 |
| Someone Else   | someone.else@mail.com   | b           |          9.2 |
| Another Person | another.person@mail.com | a           |          3.5 |
| Another Person | another.person@mail.com | b           |          7.5 |
+----------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

It seems that the pandas [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) method is on the right track, but I'm not entirely sure what my `id_vars` are and what my `value_vars` are in this situation. Also it seems to delete all columns that aren't in one of these two categories, e.g. the email address. But I want to keep all this information.

How can I do this with Pandas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) + [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for change columns names:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('rating_','')
df = df.melt(id_vars=['name','email'], var_name='rating_type', value_name='rating_value')
print (df)
             name                     email rating_type  rating_value
0         Someone          someone@mail.com           a           7.8
1    Someone Else     someone.else@mail.com           a           2.4
2  Another Person  another.persone@mail.com           a           3.5
3         Someone          someone@mail.com           b           9.9
4    Someone Else     someone.else@mail.com           b           9.2
5  Another Person  another.persone@mail.com           b           7.5
```

Another solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('rating_','')
df = df.set_index(['name','email'])
       .stack()
       .rename_axis(['name','email','rating_type'])
       .reset_index(name='rating_value')
print (df)
             name                     email rating_type  rating_value
0         Someone          someone@mail.com           a           7.8
1         Someone          someone@mail.com           b           9.9
2    Someone Else     someone.else@mail.com           a           2.4
3    Someone Else     someone.else@mail.com           b           9.2
4  Another Person  another.persone@mail.com           a           3.5
5  Another Person  another.persone@mail.com           b           7.5
```

Solution with `melt` if need change order of rows:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('rating_','')
df = df.reset_index() \
       .melt(id_vars=['index','name','email'], 
             var_name='rating_type',
             value_name='rating_value')\
       .sort_values(['index','rating_type']) \
       .drop('index', axis=1) \
       .reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
             name                     email rating_type  rating_value
0         Someone          someone@mail.com           a           7.8
1         Someone          someone@mail.com           b           9.9
2    Someone Else     someone.else@mail.com           a           2.4
3    Someone Else     someone.else@mail.com           b           9.2
4  Another Person  another.persone@mail.com           a           3.5
5  Another Person  another.persone@mail.com           b           7.5
```